# How to find Edittext by id in a dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, dialog

I have a Dialog with an EditText, there, it asks for a wallet, and users write it.

After that, this wallet should be stored in a String, but it says that it's null.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

If I use an EditText from the Activity, it works fine. But it fails when I do it from the Dialog EditText (eTW).

There is my code.

```
private void showDialog(){
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_walletdialog);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg_window);

    ImageView btnClose = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
    Button btnSend = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    EditText wallet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTW);
    String value;
```

Comment: Your code does not show a dialog. Nor does it try to get a text.

Comment: we can understand what ur tring to say but please update your question to make it more clear and precise. I dont think we need to change your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `eTW` is defined in your walletdialog xml layout file, replace

```
EditText wallet = findViewById(R.id.eTW);
```

with

```
EditText wallet = dialog.findViewById(R.id.eTW);
```

Comment: you actually need not to cast it to a `EditText`. It works fine without it.

Comment: I  just wanted to correct the error, without further optimizations. But you can safely remove the `(EditText)`.

Comment: that's ok. no problem. I have anyways edited it

Comment: And I have accepted the edit. :)